# Theme with Tasks Completed Check box

Tags: 2013, branding, task-list, theme

On our Tasks lists, we are getting a solid grey box in the Completed Check box field. Even when we deactivate the custom branding and change the Theme, it still shows as:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft had solve this well known bug with the November 2014 CU.It's included in the Foundation Update of the November 2014 CU KB2899508.

Please try updating the farm with the SharePoint Foundation Update of the November 2014 CU (KB2899508)

Comment: Really?! OK, I'll try installing that CU